# reverse engineering assembly, finding addresses

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, binary-bomb

is there any way that input values (integers in my case) effect the memory address of registers? I have a problem where I need two addresses to be equivalent, but I cannot figure out how my input influences the addresses, if at all. I am reverse engineering some assembly code.

```
%rbx = 0x7fffffffe1c0
%rbp = 0x7fffffffe1d0
add $0x4, %rbx   ===> makes %rbx 0x7fffffffe1c4
cmp %rbp, %rbx   ===> need ZF to be set, it isn't
je 0x400f53 <out_of_danger>
```

Both values are pushed to stack at start of function, and %rsp is involved in a lea instruction. Input that works is 0 1 1 1 1 _ (unsure about 6th number)

[image: Assembly code]

Comment: It's a loop. `rbx` will be incremented repeatedly until it hits `rbp`. It's a `for(rbx = rsp; rbx != rbp; rbx += 4)` The addresses are not affected by the input. The loop is iterating the six numbers entered.

Comment: BTW, _" Input that works is 0 1 1 1 1"_ definitely can't be true.

Comment: @Jester It's getting me furthest in the execution, but maybe some digits are not right.

Comment: @Jester doesn't cmp %rbp, $rbx compare the addresses? How can this condition be met via input, then?

Comment: That will be met automatically. It's iterating the array. Will be true once the whole array has been processed. Does not depend on the input values.

Comment: figured it out @Jester. Thanks for the help